# How do I setup an Azure Devops pipeline to a GitLab repo?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, gitlab, azure-pipelines

Boss wants me to set up a pipeline in Azure Devops to our Gitlab repos. I have a few questions:

1. Do I set it up under "Git other"? Should I mirror the repositories into Azure Devops?
2. I am supposed to set it up with a docker image, do I need to use docker hub?

I've never set up a pipeline and I am just a lost intern, thanks for any advice.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 3):

> Do I set it up under "Git other"?

Yes, you could use the `Git other` to create a Service connections for the
GitLab. And there is an extension [GitLab Integration for Azure Pipelines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onlyutkarsh.gitlab-integration),
which could be able to download the sources from a GitLab repository (using
clone command) and use downloaded sources in Azure Pipelines.

> Should I mirror the repositories into Azure Devops?

If you have no plans to migrate gitlab repo to azure devops repo, you do not need to mirror the repositories into Azure Devops. Besides, just as LJ said, since the YAML structure does not support for Gitlab at this moment, we could not use YAML structure with Gitlab repo.

> I am supposed to set it up with a docker image, do I need to use
> docker hub?

This is a matter of taste. In addition to [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com), you can also use [Azure Container Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/acr-template?view=azure-devops).

Comment: I was using gitlab project repo in Azure pipeline without mirroring it by cloning git http url. But recently, after enabling MFA, it breaks. And not sure whether swith to SSH will resolve it ?

Answer (score 2):

`Do I set it up under "Git other"? Should I mirror the repositories into Azure Devops?`

If you want to set up the pipeline using the `YAML` structure and have all the features that Azure DevOps provides, you have to mirror the repository since it's not possible yet to use the `YAML` file to run pipelines directly from GitLab and `Git other` connection has some limitations.

`I am supposed to set it up with a docker image, do I need to use docker hub?`

For the pipeline environment, you can use `VM Images` provided by Azure.